# Apache Flink - how do I specify an external application.conf file

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink streaming application which has been developed with an application.conf file in the JAR.  However, I want to be able to explicitly specify an external application.conf when I invoke **flink run** using the yD option as shown below:

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster -yid "appName" -yD "env.java.opts=-Dconfig.file=/path/to/application.conf" -yn 1 -yjm 1024 -ytm 7000 -p 8 -d /usr/lib/flink/lib/MyFlinkApp.jar
```

However the config in the JAR is still being used.  Is anyone able to pinpoint what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you access the `application.conf`? The way you specified the new path, it will be set as a dynamic property with name `config.file`.

Comment: @TillRohrmann I have tried doing passing it using -yD env.java.opts and then use System.getProperty("config.file.path") in the code. The property doesn't get propagated to the application. Can you please help?
    ./bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -p 1 -yjm 1024m -ytm 1024m -j /your/app/jar -yD env.java.opts="-Dconfig.file.path=/path/to/application.conf"

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the configure file to "resources" dict and package it into jar, then you can access the file in Flink as follows:

```
getClass.getResourceAsStream("/you-conf.file")
```